# Spawning tasks for asynchronous work in OpenMP

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, hpc, multicore

I am new to openMP and I was wondering if someone can review my approach.

Problem: I have sequential arrival of data from a device which has data from many sensors. I think I can parallely process analytics on each data packet to increase resolution.

Solution I thought of is as follows - but it ends up in deadlocks

This is pseudocode - so please ignore the syntax

```
TOTAL_SENSORS = 1000

omp_lock_t sensor_locks[TOTAL_SENSORS]

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp for
    for(int i=0;i<TOTAL_SENSORS;i++)
    {
        omp_init_lock(&sensor_locks[i]);
    }

#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single 

while (! end_of_data){
    
    for sensor_data in packed_data.iterator()
    {
        if sensor_data.sensor_type = 'A'
        {
            #omp task firstprivate(sensor_data)
            {
                omp_set_lock(&sensor_locks[sensor_data.sensor_id]);
                compute_analytics_type_A(sensor_data)
                omp_unset_lock(&sensor_locks[sensor_data.sensor_id]);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            #omp task firstprivate(sensor_data)
            {
                omp_set_lock(&sensor_locks[sensor_data.sensor_id]);
                compute_analytics_type_B(sensor_data)
                omp_unset_lock(&sensor_locks[sensor_data.sensor_id]);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

When I try this - this leads to a deadlock.

Broadly, I am trying to parallize the computation of analytics as long as they are not being computed for the same sensor.

Can someone help with the idiomatic way of doing it ?

Comment: Can't you set some prints here and there to see at what point the program hangs?

Comment: `sensor_data` being a structure, beware how `firstprivate` makes a copy if it has pointer components.

Comment: Tried that. Couldnt figure it out. Will wait for someone with openMP experience to share perspective.

Comment: sensor_data does not have pointers.

Comment: "tried that"... So please report what you have observed. Your pseudo-code looks correct (at least to me) at first glance, so we probably need more informations to help.

Comment: Sure. I noticed that the threads spawned at #pragma omp task seem to work on the same sensor_data instead of waiting for the locks. And then everything stops. As debug, I was printing the sensor_data.sensor_id which was printing same sensor_id for all threads instead of expected different sensor_id for different sensors.

Comment: How is `sensor_data` declared? I think we need to see more code, and ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The key to parallelization is to make sure that each thread/task writes to a unique location. Is that the case? The code you posted does not show why you need a lock at all.

Comment: I will try to explain. The lock is required as there can be multiple sensor data packets which want to update the same analytic item. The lock is there to make it sequential in time for a single sensor - but parallelize for other sensors.

Comment: Just a guess ... Are all tasks using the same copy of `packed_data`? How is _that_ locked to prevent multiple tasks from changing the iterator [position]? Maybe you should post the code that defines `packed_data` and the code for `iterator`. Because you're _not_ trying to (e.g.) iterate an _array_, you might find it easier to use `pthreads` and control things "manually". Also, posting _real_ code might also help.

Comment: Also, I'm not too familiar with `omp` but a quick read of the doc implies that `omp single` would force the entire `while` loop to be run as a single thread?

Comment: @CraigEstey the `#pragma omp task` distribute the work to other threads. There's no reason to use pthreads here.

Comment: @PierU IMO, [as impl] omp is terrible for debugging. It _would_ be okay if it worked as a preprocessor (similar to `cfront` or `cpp`) that produced flat C code that you could examine, compile, and put breakpoints into. But, it creates "hidden" task functions (to impl `#pragma omp parallel for`, etc.) that are fired up in pthreads under the hood. The best bet is to look at the asm (`-S`). Or, try to guess what code is generated for each `#pragma`. [Compiling OpenMP code to C code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10616347/5382650)

Comment: @CraigEstey I use OpenMP quite a lot, and it's not more difficult to debug than any other parallel code once you know what the directives are supposed to do. Furthermore it's perfectly possible to use debuggers, breakpoints, etc, on OpenMP binaries. But effective debugging require some reproducible example, that we don't have in this discussion. It's like asking a mechanic about a problem with your car, but you don't let him open the hood.

Comment: I can see that you are asking a new question around the same code. It would be nice to have some feedback from you this question.

Comment: Yes as I received feed I thought it was better to ask a new question as perhaps this wasnt clear. I am still not sure how to proceed though. Once I incorporate the feedback will share on both questions.